# Table positioning with CSS

Tags: css, position, css-tables

[image]

It is a nested table. I want to know if is there a way where the table (the one with BG yellow) to be below the header. Because with this, it will depend on the data of the other table in its row.

Comment: Have you tried <td valign="top"> on the parent table cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the css attribute `vertical-align` to `top` on the cells of the parent table.

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align